# Menu shifting upon window re-sizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This menu should be positioned in the center of the website and cope with the resizing of the browser's window. Now it's in the center and the animation works. But whenever i try to make the menu responsive so it'll remain in the middle of the website when i resize, the animation stops. Any help please..

**Scripting**

```
$(".menu").on("click", function () {
      $(".menu").addClass('permahover');                   
 });
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    height: 40px;
    width: 180px;
    text-align: right;
    border-style: none;
}

.menu {
    width: 150px;
    height: 350px;
}

    .menu li {
        position: relative;
        top: 150px;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 690px;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        border-style: none;
    }

#item7 {
    transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
}

#item6 {
    transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
}

#item5 {
    transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
}

#item4 {
    transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
}

#item3 {
    transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
}

#item2 {
    transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
}

#item1 {
    transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
}

.permahover li {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 10%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu" class="menu">
    <ul class="headlines">
        <li id="item1" onclick="checklist(this)">
            <button onclick="myFunction()">a</button></li>
        <li id="item2">
            <button onclick="myFunction2()">b</button></li>
        <li id="item3">
            <button>c</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item4">
            <button>d</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item5">
            <button>e</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item6">
            <button>f</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item7">
            <button>g</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
$(".menu").on("click", function () {
      $(".menu").addClass('permahover');                   
 });
```

```css
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    height: 40px;
    width: 180px;
    text-align: right;
    border-style: none;
}

.menu {
    width: 150px;
    height: 350px;
}

    .menu li {
        position: relative;
        top: 150px;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 690px;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        border-style: none;
    }

#item7 {
    transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
}

#item6 {
    transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
}

#item5 {
    transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
}

#item4 {
    transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
}

#item3 {
    transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
}

#item2 {
    transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
}

#item1 {
    transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
}

.permahover li {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu" class="menu">
    <ul class="headlines">
        <li id="item1" onclick="checklist(this)">
            <button onclick="myFunction()">a</button></li>
        <li id="item2">
            <button onclick="myFunction2()">b</button></li>
        <li id="item3">
            <button>c</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item4">
            <button>d</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item5">
            <button>e</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item6">
            <button>f</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item7">
            <button>g</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How is your menu `centered`? I just tried adding a code snippet and your menu was _off screen_ to the right. Please try to put this into a SO snippet so we can easily see how you code comes together.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to remove your class on window resize. Try the following:

```
$(window).resize(function(){ 
    $(".menu").removeClass("permahover")
});
```

I would also like to mention that your menu is actually off screen to the right, and the user can actually *scroll* to that position. Wrap this entire thing into a box and hide its overflow to make sure this isn not an issue.